# Convert const to react class

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx, mobx-react

how can I change this code to a class:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      React.createElement(component, props)
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

I'm using this component in react router 4:

```
<Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={About} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Home}/>
              <Route component={NotMatch} />
</Switch>
```

But I need to change to a Class because I'm using MobX.

Something like this:

```
@inject('store')
@observer
export default class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.store = this.props.store

  }

  render () {
    return (
            <div>

            </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class code is OK for handling props like your functional component:

```
@inject('store')
@observer
export default class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.store = this.props.store;
  }

  render () {
    const { component, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={ props => (
            fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
                React.createElement(component, props)
            ) : (
                <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: '/login',
                    state: { from: props.location }
                }}/>
            )
        )}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: All is working fine, but you need to add const to: { component, ...rest } = this.props;

Comment: What is ...rest? :) Thanks!

Comment: Yep forgot the const, thanks! `...rest` simply puts rest of the properties of `this.props` object in a rest object.   take a look at [this link](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)